nginx server hosted on AWS ECS does not respond back with CLOSE_NOTIFY
One of our clients recently updated their infrastructure as part of their ongoing security
maintenance exercise which includes an OpenSSL library update (from V1 to V3).
Unfortunately, OpenSSL 3 has a much more strict behaviour about unexpected EOF -
which is triggered when a mandatory close_notify alert is not sent out by their
peer (i.e. in this case, Our APIs) before closing a TLS connection
On our side, NGINX ECS service sits in front of our APIs. So the flow is
Client Service --- NGINX ECS Service -- Application ECS Service
We have tried to simulate the flow by trying to call the Application service endpoints using Open SSL V1 and also with Open SSL v3 client.
Open SSL v1 (uses TLSv1.2) client sends a close_notify alert and the nginx server does respond back with TLS v1.2 and a close_notify alert. However, when Open SSL v3 (uses TLS v1.3) client is used the nginx server responds back with TLS v1.3 but does not send the close_notify alert.
As per the link https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-tls-rfc8446bis-03.html, since TLS v1.3 it is not mandatory to send close_notify. WHat I could figure out is sending close_notify is not mandatory but if not sent would cause truncation

Each party MUST send a "close_notify" alert before closing its write side of the connection, unless it has already sent some error alert. This does not have any effect on its read side of the connection. Note that this is a change from versions of TLS prior to TLS 1.3 in which implementations were required to react to a "close_notify" by discarding pending writes and sending an immediate "close_notify" alert of their own. That previous requirement could cause truncation in the read side. Both parties need not wait to receive a "close_notify" alert before closing their read side of the connection, though doing so would introduce the possibility of truncation.

Our Nginx Configuration is as below. Kindly advise if there is any way to send the close_notify alert using TLSv1.3 and what should be tested for regression.
cat <<EOF >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        server {
                listen 443 ssl;
                server_name $mtls;
                access_log /dev/stdout main;
                ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/${mtls}.crt";
                ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/${mtls}.key";
                
              

                ssl_client_certificate  "/etc/nginx/ca.crt";

                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers ${ssl_ciphers_flag};
                ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
                ssl_verify_client on;
                ssl_verify_depth 2;
                ssl_dhparam "/etc/nginx/dhparam.pem";
                ssl_ciphers ${ssl_ciphers_list};
                ssl_buffer_size 8k;
                location / {B
                    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                    proxy_set_header        Client_Hostname \${ssl_server_name};
                    proxy_set_header        Cert_Thumbprint \${san};
                    proxy_set_header        Host \${ssl_server_name};
                    proxy_set_header        x-apigw-api-id ${mtls_apigateway_id};
                    proxy_pass https://${vpc_endpoint_dns}/${DEPLOY_ENV}/;
            }
        }
EOF

